# Is there an accepted abbreviation for 'Abundance'?

Tags: notation

I want to represent the product of the abundance of hydrogen and the mass of hydrogen.  Same for helium, but I can't find an abbreviation.  What notation would I use for:$$\frac{\rho_B}{Abundance_H\space m_H+Abundance_{He}\space m_{He}}$$As this looks clumsy.

Comment: Why not just define a variable?

Comment: I'm not trying to solve a problem.  I'm trying to communicate what I'm doing and how I did it.

Comment: .. just say "$A_Hm_H$ where $A_H$ is the abundance of Hydrogen"

Comment: I am looking for notation that would be recognized by a wide audience.  If I were to make up some notation when there was an accepted abbreviation, I would look foolish.  Yes, I can use the variable $s$ to mean the speed of light, but if my paper had $E=m\space s^2$, that would make it more difficult to understand.

Comment: You'd have to define "abundance* as well.  I can't remember hearing it in a physics context; I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 2):

This has basically already been said in the comments, but I thought it might be good to post it as an answer.

As you found, there seems to be no widespread (i.e. that it can be found by a quick google search) abbreviation for abundance. However, assuming you write some sort of text where you use this formula, you could "define" an abbreviation for abundance:

> ...
> $$\frac{\rho_B}{A_H\cdot m_H+A_{He}\cdot m_{He}}$$
>
> (where $A$ is abundance)
>
> ...

Using $A$ seems like the easiest option (assuming it is not used in a different context in your document already), and I also found that [Natural abundance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_abundance) uses the abbreviation $NA$.